# Checking the login from my MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have code here that checks the login from my MySQL table i am then looking to carry my session over but it doesen't seem to be working.

This code is checking my login it is the check_login.php

```
 <?php

    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="student"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="login"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect1");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 

    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
    //$sqlaccesslevel="SELECT AccessLevel FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    //$resultaccesslevel = mysql_query($sqlaccesslevel) or die(mysql_error());

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    if ($result)
      $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    else
      $count = 0;

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to the website"
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = "$username";


    header("location:student.html");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password. YOU LOOSE. GOOD DAY SIR.";
    }


    ?>
```

This is my login.html page when the user enters the details are posted to my check_login.php

```
  <html>
    <head> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="check_login.php">
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong>Student Login</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="78">Username</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </form>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And I am outputting it to student.html the login seems to be working but the session is not carrying any help is much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<h1>hello
</h1>

<?php  // this starts the session 
 session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION["sessionusername"]) )
{
header("location:student.html");
}
 // echo variable from the session, we set this on our other page 
 echo "Welcome":  
  echo $_SESSION['user'];
?>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `session_start();` on top of your php file, and also [read this topic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) it's about use sessions in php and config directives.

Answer (score 0):

First of all put **session_start();** at the top of your **check_login.php** page.
Now where you are printing the session value as

```
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

it should be:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

as your session variable name is **username** and not **user**.

Also once you have started the session you dont need to start it again on every page wherever you want to use the session variables.